# Why this condition is always true?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

quiz.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let q of categoryid;">
<li colspan="4">
    <strong>Q.No. {{q.questionId}}</strong>  
    {{q.questionName}} 
</li>
<li>
    <ul *ngFor="let o of q.options; let i = index" 
        (click)="selectedIndex = (i+q.questionId)">
        <div>
           <li 
              [ngClass]="{correctAnswer: o.Ans && selectedIndex===(i + q.questionId),
                          wrongAnswer: !o.Ans && selectedIndex===(i+q.questionId)}">
               <strong>{{o.Ans}}</strong>  {{o.optionName}}
           </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

[firebase database is look like this](https://ibb.co/JB0PMzc)

`correctAnswer` class is always `true`. Why?

Comment: Did you debug and see what the values are?

Comment: Please include code/data as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"false" string is actually treated as a *true* boolean expression, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

In order to fix this you either have to provide a boolean value to your o object ({Ans: false} instead of {Ans: "false"}) or run a different check like this: o.Ans === "true". You might also consider using type conversion equality check like o.Ans == true but I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name should be in single quotes and put condition statements into brackets:

```
<li
   [ngClass]="{'correctAnswer': (o.Ans && selectedIndex === (i + q.questionId)),
               'wrongAnswer': (!o.Ans && selectedIndex === (i+q.questionId)})">
   <strong>{{o.Ans}}</strong>  {{o.optionName}}
</li>
```

or you can use ternary operator `?`:

```
<li
   [ngClass]="(o.Ans && selectedIndex === (i + q.questionId)) ? 'correctAnswer' : 'wrongAnswer'">
   <strong>{{o.Ans}}</strong>  
   {{o.optionName}}
</li>
```

In addition, you can show debug info in your HTML and see how expression is evaluated:

```
<p>(o.Ans && selectedIndex === (i + q.questionId)) is 
    {{ (o.Ans && selectedIndex === (i + q.questionId)) }}</p> 

<p>(!o.Ans && selectedIndex === (i+q.questionId)}) is 
    (!o.Ans && selectedIndex === (i+q.questionId)})</p>
```